# search through array to match to user input (java)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am wondering how to search through this array to match it to the users answer, obviously the 8th line is incorrect and that's where I'm lost.

```
 public static void THELASTQ() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] bands = {"guantanamo baywatch", "levitation room", "allah las", "los pesos", "tijuana panthers"};

    System.out.println("give me a band name.");
    String bandInput = scanner.nextLine();

    if(bandInput.contains(bands))
    {
        System.out.print("whats their best song?");
        String bestSong = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("I love " + bestSong);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: switch it bands contains bandInput have you to use arrays? Because array don't have a contain function you have to loop through the values and check every element

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the method that you use to compare the input of the user. You can change the condition to "if(Arrays.asList(bands).contains(bandInput))".

**Example**

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Main {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] bands = {"guantanamo baywatch", "levitation room", "allah las", "los pesos", "tijuana panthers"};
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(bands).contains("allah las"));
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Because you use an array here includes will not work. You have to go through your array and check each item if it is equal to the string from the user input.

For the comparison you should use the `.equal()` method of string

```
package hall;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class H {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        H.THELASTQ();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unlikely-arg-type")
    public static void THELASTQ() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] bands = {"guantanamo baywatch", "levitation room", "allah las", "los pesos", "tijuana panthers"};

        System.out.println("give me a band name.");
        String bandInput = scanner.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < bands.length; i++) {
            if(bands[i].equals(bandInput))
            {
                System.out.print("whats their best song?");
                String bestSong = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("I love " + bestSong);
            }
        }
        
        

    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem because that the condition is incorrect

I suggest to use the following code

```java
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] bands = {"guantanamo baywatch", "levitation room",
                       "allah las", "los pesos", "tijuana panthers"};

    System.out.println("give me a band name.");
    String bandInput = scanner.nextLine();
    
    for(String userInput : bands){
        if(bandInput.equals(userInput)){
           System.out.print("The input was found: "+userInput);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what did you do on the 8th line if you dont mind me asking? are you just matching it? i kind of got lost there, and thanks the code works now

Comment: Okay bro, no problem.